# DynamoDB Upsert - Update or Create?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, upsert

We use DynamoDB `UpdateItem`.

This acts as an "upsert" as we can learn [from the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html)

> Edits an existing item's attributes, or adds a new item to the table if it does not already exist. [...]

When we make a request, to determine if an item was created or an existing item was updated, we request [ALL_OLD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-ReturnValues). This works great and allows us to differentiate between `update` and `create`.

As an additional requirement we also want to return `ALL_NEW`, but still know the type of operation that was performed.

Question: Is this possible to do in a single request or do we have to make a second (get) request?

Comment: Can't you just calculate the state of ALL_NEW by applying the update operations to the ALL_OLD response?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The update operation might only update _some_ fields, while `ALL_NEW` returns pre-existing field as well.

Comment: Maybe we misunderstand each other. You issue an `UpdateItem` call with the update expression of things to be changed and the response gives you the item as it appeared before the change. You can just create a copy of the old item in memory and apply the changes from your update expression to it.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Thank you for enlightening me here in my ignorance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default this is not supported in DynamoDB, there is no `ALL` or `NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES` as there is in DynamoDB streams, but you can always go DIY.

When you do the `UpdateItem` call, you have the `UpdateExpression`, which is basically the list of changes to apply to the item. Given that you told DynamoDB to return the item as it looked like **before** that operation, you can construct the new state locally.

Just create a copy of the `ALL_OLD` response and locally apply the changes from the `UpdateExpression` to it. That's definitely faster than two API calls at the cost of a slightly more complex implementation.